# php не отправляется запрос

Tags: php

Есть простая форма регистрации

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input name="login">
    <input name="password" type="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Реализую регистрацию следующим образом

```
session_start();

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$name = 'users';

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $name);
     
if (!empty($_POST['login']) and !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if (empty($user)) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO users SET login='$login', password='$password'";
        mysqli_query($link, $query);

        $_SESSION['auth'] = true;
        $id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    } else {
        echo 'Login is unavailable';
    }
}
```

Первый запрос в базу проходит (проверяю логин), а вот второй на вставку в бд (собственно регистрация) - нет. Просветите в чем беда.

Comment: читаем дубликат - в частности: включить все ошибки, отладка

Comment: И как обычно SQL-инъекции. Да кто ж вас всех так учит-то?

Comment: Ошибки включены но ничего не выводит. На запрос возвращает false.

Comment: значит запрос неверный. надо смотреть полностью сформированный запрос, выполнить его в бд и посмотреть ошибку....... хотя mysqli есть такая штука как  https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php

Comment: А лучше для начала изучить синтаксис базовых запросов Mysql и понять что insert into пишется по-другому

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  INSERT INTO поддерживает оба варианта: и через `VALUES` и через `SET`.

Comment: @u_mulder для этого нужно ставить специальное расширение. А стандартный синтаксис другой. И пользуются им в 99% случаев, исключение составляют извращенцы))

Comment: var_dump($user) что выводит? (после SELECT запроса)